# How to type a multidimensional accumulator using reduce?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Suppose I have the following:

```
const elements = [
    { fieldA: true },
    { fieldB: true },
    { fieldA: true, fieldB: true },
    { fieldB: true },
    { fieldB: true },
];

const [withFieldA, withoutFieldA] = elements.reduce(
    (acc, entry) => {
        const { fieldA } = entry;

        const hasField = Boolean(fieldA);

        return acc[+!hasField].push(entry) && acc;
    },
    [[], []],
);

console.log('withFieldA', withFieldA);
console.log('withoutFieldA', withoutFieldA);
```

This code works, but I'm getting TS errors.

I've tried doing,

```
type TElement = {
    fieldA?: boolean;
    fieldB?: boolean;
}

const elements = [
    { fieldA: true },
    { fieldB: true },
    { fieldA: true, fieldB: true },
    { fieldB: true },
    { fieldB: true },
] as TElement[]

const [withFieldA, withoutFieldA]: [TElement[], TElement[]] = elements.reduce(
. . . . .
```

But that didn't seem to work.

How can I properly type this?

[Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=14&ssc=79&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgogGwgWwgO2FAvFA3gKCiKgDMBLCBAEwEEB+ALigCMB7VpAQzQG5DjylKgCFGLdl174AvvnwBjVmgDOmSinTBl2KAG1+RXKQrUaTYACcArtGkAaA3mNDh567YfEng025t3nalcoSxsoe0cjHxE-D0jAmJD3cIcAXShObXgkVAxdVLlFFUxdAHcyYAALADETWgDyqtYrYFqhGlSmXWyNPNSAntzgfPScdSHlADoLCCoreQgACkdFznl5AM0LEABKbAA+PEcvItUjrwuBOppj4mkdLZA+W6JTzErMtuodYQkIbkW0RoO2elyIM2AVgsaAy610AGoAIQfZRfKipSZgKzKSqLR57ABkBNh8j4XgiXl0+QCIwcIMKSmUHAgkwQrAA5osAOSNGrXLkNCp89r007M1kc7m85qtfmCpotNHAnhAA)

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) - A bunch of code without any explanation on what it does is not a _good question_. Also the phrase _"doesn't work"_ is totally useless. What is supposed to happen, what happens instead, any errors, ...

Comment: Where does `{ fieldA: true, fieldB: true }` go? Currently in the `fieldA` bin... but...??

Answer (score 0):

You might need to use array of arrays type `EntityType[][]`

Here is a [Typescript Playground without errors](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgogGwgWwgO2FAvFA3gKCiKgDMBLCBAEwEEB%20ALigCMB7VpAQzQG5DjylKgCFGLdl174AvvnwBjVmgDOmSinTBl2KAG1%20RXKQrUaTYACcArtGkAaA3mNDh567YfEng025t3nalcoSxsoe0cjHxE-D0jAmJD3cIcAXShObXgkVAxdVLlFFUxdAHcyYAALADETWgDyqtYrYFqhGnScdVytADoLCCoreQgACkdRznl5AM0LEABKbAA%20PEcvItU1rx2BOpp14mkdOZA%20Q6JNzErMtuodYQkIblHomgXz3culLbeaCwsnBAOim8l0AAZUnwvlArglhP9AcCcKDdABGKFyGFkEhQUY3ZR3KhLAgwrx-AFA3pgKzKSqjU4fC7hKCUZTQUlkojRBGUkDU2n0xnQr6yZkDYBWCxoPQUpEBHmIoGYrwRLy6fIBfLpTKwRAaPKpTX4JkKH4cCC9BCsADmowA5I0avt7Q0Ks72kzNharbaHU7mq0XW6mi0ie8eEA)

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems:

1. Typescript is unable to infer your accumulator type
2. You're returning an integer and not the accumulator

### 1. add a type to your accumulator

```
const [withFieldA, withoutFieldA] = elements.reduce(
    (acc, entry: TElement) => {
      // code
    },
    [[], []] as [TElement[], TElement[]], // <-- you need this
);
```

### 2. keep your returns simple

This return statement is confusing `return acc[+!hasField].push(entry) && acc;`. `push` returns the new length of the array... so you're returning a number and not actually the accumulator.

```
const [withFieldA, withoutFieldA] = elements.reduce(
    (acc, entry: TElement) => {
        const {
            fieldA
        } = entry;

        const hasField = Boolean(fieldA);
        acc[+!hasField].push(entry); // push first
        return acc; // then return
    },
    [[], []] as [TElement[], TElement[]],
);
```

[typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgogGwgWwgO2FAvFA3gKCiKgDMBLCBAEwEEB%20ALigCMB7VpAQzQG5DjylKgCFGLdl174AvvnwBjVmgDOmSinTBl2KAG1%20RXKQrUaTYACcArtGkAaA3mNDh567YfEng025t3nalcoSxsoe0cjHxE-D0jAmJD3cIcAXShObXgkVAxdVLlFFUxdAHcyYAALADETWgDyqtYrYFqhGnScdVytADoLCCoreQgACkdRznl5AM0LECZsjQwASmwAPjxHLyLVLa8DgTqabeJpHTmQPlOiXcxKzLbqHWEJCG5R6JoVvkOiKfkugA1ABCB7KJ5UVK9MBWZSVUaXFY3KADYBWCxoDLTX5nTzEXT5AL5dKZPRLHpE2CIZbAEkOH6FJTKDgQXoIVgAc1GAHJGjVjjyGhUBe1GbtWeyubz%20c1WoLhU0WpDvjwgA)